# Vector of size -1 crashes flash player with no error handling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector, crash, runtime-error

Interesting bug I found in Flash player 11 today. It may be in other versions as well. I can instantly crash the flash player browser with one line of code, throws no runtime errors, and exits with just one message if you have debug traces enabled: "error: out of memory".

constructing a vector with a size of -1.

```
var vector:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(-1);
```

And poof, your whole application gives up. Array at least throws runtime errors with "out of bounds". How is this not caught? And could it lead to exploits, since it is unhandled?

Anyone else experience this?
I tested it in version 11.4.31.110 and 11.2.202.235

Comment: As far as i see in fp 16, this problem still persists. Flash just crashes when vector can't be allocated, including the case when you try to extract BitmapData's pixels to vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably because the constructor is expecting an unsigned int (only positive numbers).

converting -1 to an unsigned int yields 4,294,967,295, which would make the out of memory error make more sense. might make sense to submit a bug report. otherwise, don't do that :)

Answer (score 1):

How can negative memory be allocated?

[Vector.<T>() constructor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#Vector%28%29) expects an unsigned int and boolean as parameters:

```
public function Vector(length:uint = 0, fixed:Boolean = false)
```

> - length:uint (default = 0) — The initial length (number of elements) of the Vector. If this parameter is greater than zero, the specified
>     number of Vector elements are created and populated with the default
>     value appropriate to the base type (null for reference types).
> - fixed:Boolean (default = false) — Whether the Vector's length is fixed (true) or can be changed (false). This value can also be set
>     using the fixed property.

As well, accessing Vector's `length` property is also `uint`.

Subtracting 1 from 0 would cause [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), which is likely your error.

If you're attempting to programmatically derive state by initializing to -1, you should set the vector to `null` instead.

Comment: Thank Jason, I am not actually trying to set the length to -1, I discovered it when the length was a variable, mistakenly set to -1. What I found shocking was no runtime error trapping for this situation, as array does. Took me over an hour to track it down, as I had no stack traces whatsoever.